# Returning longest consecutive sequence of ranging integers

Tags: python, list, integer

## The Problem

**tl;dr** - The code below shows an algorithm I'm looking to improve by trying some kind of different approach.

Now the long explanation.

Given a list of integers, I would like to find every sequence of consecutive integers that are either the same as the original starting point of the sequence, or higher. The sequence should also be longer than a higher-ranked consecutive sequence.
You're probably pretty confused. Let me just illustrate what I mean.

When I have a list of integers, I can spread it out to represent its ranges. Example:

```
2,1,1,3,3,1
```

becomes

```
-,-,-,3,3,-
2,-,-,2,2,-
1,1,1,1,1,1
```

As you can see, each integer value is in its respective row and decremented values fill the column beneath it. Note that the above procedure does not have to be executed in the algorithm.

I would now like to return every sequence on one level/row that is not completely covered up by another sequence.
For example, here, there is no 0 in the list, meaning that the base line of ones has maximal length. One of the returned values would now be [1, 6, 5]: 1 for the number that the sequence consists of, 6 for the length of the sequence, 5 for the final index of the sequence.
For the middle row, we only have twos. Let's analyse it. The first sequence here is the single two at the beginning. It has the return value of [2,1,0]. Then there are two blanks, after which another 2 twos follow. But wait! Don't add them yet! The sequence of twos is completely covered by the threes above. So actually, we're finished in this row.
In the top row, we can add the sequence of threes: [3,2,4]
The final output is now

```
[[1,6,5],[2,1,0],[3,2,4]]
```

#### A few more examples

For clarification, here are a few examples. They are 100% complete and correct, I have checked them multiple times.

```
[3,3,3,2,1] -> [[1,5,4],[2,4,3],[3,3,2]] 

[7,7,3,0,1,2,3] -> [[1,3,6],[2,2,6],[3,3,2],[3,1,6],[7,2,1]]

[0,0,0] -> []

[0,1,0,4,0,1,0] -> [[1,1,1],[4,1,3],[1,1,5]]
```

## My Approach so far

I thought of a rather complex approach, which is iterating over the values in the list from the highest occurrence to 1. Whenever I come across a sequence, I would save it and then decrement all the elements of it by one. Before I do the latter, though, I check if the values either left or right of the sequence's starting and ending index respectively are lower than the number in the sequence. For example, this is true in the following cases:

```
[2,4,4,4,1], looking at 3*4
[1,8,8], looking at 2*8
[9,9,9,8], looking at 3*9
[9,7,4], looking at 2*7 (sequence doesn't formally exist as [7,7], 
                         but would be in the results, as described above)
```

If that is the case, then I decrement all values of the sequence to fit in with their surroundings.

Let's run through that procedure with a simple list:

```
[4,4,2,1,1,3]
```

We start by checking for all fours. There are two right at the beginning, how convenient! Doesn't have a value left of it, and the value right of it is 2 ... so that one is 2 points smaller. So ... we can happily decrement all elements of the list. Before, though, we pass the value of the sequence ([4,2,1]) to a variable. After that, we read the highest surrounding integer value, assign it to all elements of the sequence and get:

```
[2,2,2,1,1,3]
```

Aha! Now it's evened out with the 2 on the right. All we need to do now is check if there are any integers with the value 3. Well, huzzah, there is that one little guy sitting in the corner. Again, we save the value of the sequence ([3,1,5]) and assign every element the highest surrounding integer, which happens to be 1:

```
[2,2,2,1,1,1]
```

And again. We return [2,3,2].

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Why, doesn't that look familiar. All we have to do is return [1,6,5] and we're done here.

The final output is [[4,2,1],[3,1,5],[2,3,2],[1,6,5]].

Too lazy to go through more example... This post is getting too long anyways.

#### Code

Yes, I already have some code for this. Here it is:

```
def ListProcessing(listL, length, freq):

    #to detect end of array and not miss out on last sequences
    listL.extend([0])

    #Iterating over all unique elements that appear in the list from top to
    #bottom, leaving out elements under or equal to _length_
    for checkNum in reversed(list(set(sorted(listL))-set(range(length)))):
        seqLen = 0
        #Iterate over list
        for index, val in enumerate(listL):
            #current element higher than checkNum?
            #Yes -> increase counter of the sequence length
            if val >= checkNum:
                seqLen += 1
            #No -> Reset seqLen. If seqLen is high enough, replace sequence with
            #      sequence of highest neighbouring elements and yield the seq.
            else:
                if seqLen > freq-1:
                    newVal = max(val, listL[index-seqLen-1])
                    listL[index-seqLen:index] = [newVal] * seqLen
                    yield(checkNum, seqLen, index-1)
                seqLen = 0
```

AFAIK it does exactly what I want it to do.

## So - What's the Question?

As summarised above, my algorithm already works. Yet the approach seems kind of complex, and I am sure that there is a better way. I would love to hear of an alternate approach.
Currently working on implementing this with the array.array module to make it faster. If anyone wants to have a try at implementing his own approach with it, I'd be absolutely thrilled.

Even unimplemented concepts/ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, here is another approach to solving it. Lets take an example, `seq = [4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2]`. Notice that we can begin by returning the the result associated with the longest possible sequence that follows the rules laid out in your question. That result will have the form `[min(seq), len(seq), len(seq) - 1]` or `[1, 7, 6]`.

Now you know that all other valid results must only contain values greater than `min(seq)` so we can split `seq` into two sub-sequences, `[4, 4, 2]` and `[3, 2]` and look for valid results in those sub sequences. We can repeat this splitting process for each of the sub sequence recursively until we're out of sub-sequences.

In code that would look like this:

```
def recListProcessing(seq, threshold=0, min_len=1):
    len_seq = len(seq)
    if len_seq < min_len:
        return

    min_value = min(seq)
    if min_value > threshold:
        yield (min_value, len_seq, len_seq - 1)

    start = 0
    while start < len_seq:
        try:
            end = seq.index(min_value, start)
        except ValueError:
            end = len_seq
        sub_seq = seq[start:end]
        for item in recListProcessing(sub_seq, threshold, min_len):
            yield (item[0], item[1], item[2] + start)
        start = end + 1
```

Comment: Great Approach! I didn't even think of the above facts. According to some profiling runs I did, it even seems to be slightly faster. Thank you very much, this helped me out a lot :)